# removing ip proxy-arp

Tags: is-is

I would like to understand from experts here what could be potential things that can go wrong of disabling ip proxy-arp

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that proxy ARP won't work any more.

However, proxy ARP is nothing that is required for a normal network. Proxy ARP enables you to 'fake' a remote device into an L2 segment - the gateway replies to ARP request for the fake IP addresses with its own MAC, so that packets get sent its way and can be forwarded to the actual destination (often while translating the destination address). In a nutshell, proxy ARP enables forwarding across a gateway without the source host being aware that a gateway is used.

It is nothing that a proper network requires. If you don't know whether any of your services requires that proxy ARP config I'd recommend running a packet capture for a while, listening for ARP requests for the ARPed IP address. If you discover that it's still in use make sure it's documented properly this time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say it's still an issue with modern firewalls, but there's the remote possibility disabling proxy-arp can prevent the firewall from answering for non-interface addresses. For example, a static NAT entry for an address on the LAN subnet that's not a direct interface address. (an "alias" in some configs) i.e. a.b.c.1 (gw), 2 (fw), 3 (nat for server1), ... Since "3" isn't assigned to an interface, but the firewall needs to act as it if it were... *proxy-arp*. That's not technically how proxy-arp is defined, but that's what firewalls mean by it.

(*proxy-arp* is something from a time long long lost. With proxy-arp, one could set their gateway to "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 <interface>" and something on the LAN would answer the ARP if it knew how to get there; potentially multiple somethings.)